# mySQL query select row if given columns value different from previous row

Tags: mysql

So I have this database table with some records and I would like to only select a row if its different from previous based on few columns ( C1, C2, C3 ) .. ignoring date and all other columns .. I want to check against these 3 columns and bring only a row if its different from previous. Need some help here.

```
Name    C1  C2  C3  Date
Test    Y   Y   Y   10/23/2017 0:00:00
Test    Y   Y   Y   10/24/2017 0:00:00
Test    N   Y   Y   10/25/2017 0:00:00
Test    Y   Y   N   10/26/2017 0:00:00
Test    Y   Y   N   10/27/2017 0:00:00
Test    Y   Y   Y   10/28/2017 0:00:00
Test    Y   Y   Y   10/30/2017 0:00:00
```

The result I want is should be like this:

```
Name    C1  C2  C3  Date
Test    Y   Y   Y   10/23/2017 0:00:00
Test    N   Y   Y   10/25/2017 0:00:00
Test    Y   Y   N   10/26/2017 0:00:00
Test    Y   Y   Y   10/28/2017 0:00:00
```

Comment: why last row in your expected result have the same data as the first row ?

Comment: should it be group-ed to ?

Comment: @Gagantous everytime a row is different from its immediate previous row, I want to select it. But it does not matter if its same first row or different from first row .. makes sense?

Comment: What have you tried? What parts can you do? Please read & act on [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you store dates as dates, here's one idea...

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM my_table a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.date) next 
         FROM my_table x 
         LEFT 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.name = x.name 
          AND y.date > x.date 
        GROUP  
           BY x.Name
            , x.Date
     ) b 
    ON b.Name = a.Name 
   AND b.next = a.date 
   AND b.c1=a.c1 
   AND b.c2=a.c2 
   AND b.c3 = a.c3
 WHERE b.Name IS NULL;
```

Comment: what is b.next?
why b.Name is NULL?

Comment: b.next is the next row (when ordered by name and date). NULL filters for ‘next rows’ where a,b and c values are not the same as the previous.

Comment: oh ok and about 
AND b.c1=a.c1 
   AND b.c2=a.c2 
   AND b.c3 = a.c3
isn't it supposed to be <> instead of = ?

Comment: of course not .. i read it wrong.. makes sense but does not work. :(

Comment: Works just fine

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.c1, t.c2, t.c3) <>
       (select t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
        from t t2
        where t2.name = t.name and t2.date < t.date
        order by t2.date desc
        limit 1
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

### the logic is very simple concatenate all requested columns and rank them and then select

```html
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        p.CC,
            p.C1,
            p.C2,
            p.C3,
            p.C4,
            CASE
                WHEN @prev_value = CC THEN @rank_count
                WHEN @prev_value:=CC THEN @rank_count:=@rank_count + 1
            END AS rank
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        CONCAT(C2, C3, C4) AS CC, t.*
    FROM
        mytbl t) p, (SELECT @rank_count:=0, @prev_value:=NULL) r) q
WHERE
    q.rank IS NULL
```

---

Thanks.
BR,
Muhammad.